# Search on MSE is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

[image]

I was trying to use the in page search to find a post and... it doesn't work. It just does nothing for a long while, then throws me a we're currently offline for maintenance.

While I use an unsupported browser - Vivaldi 3.0.1874.23, another user reports the same issue on firefox on windows.

I wish I could give more information, but this is what I have. Jokes about SE search being *more* broken than usual aside, can we have this fixed please?

Comment: Chrome on Ubuntu too; it's not caused by your browser.

Comment: I can reproduce on Chrome, Firefox, *and* Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Confirmed on Firefox/Win 10 too, can't search on any site. "We are currently offline for maintenance"

Comment: It's network wide.

Comment: Interesting. It told me posting had failed

Comment: Conveying a message from Nick: "We are seeing some abnormal search traffic we're investigating and working to resolve any disruptions still present."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [tweeted by Nick Craver](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1292101436319379456), this is now fixed:

> Search has been re-enabled across the Stack Exchange network. Apologies for the interruption.